# Finding most occurences of objects by a particular field in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an arraylist of objects which contain information on calls made to a particular destination number.  I have been trying to figure out the best way to search this list and return the number with the most occurrences as well as the count of these occurrences (to be called from another method in a linked class).

For instance:

I have this method which adds calls to the list by calling a random number in the address book

```
public void makeCall(Phonecall call)
    {
     call = new Phonecall();
     call.setDestination(anyNumber());
     call.setDuration(0 + (int)(Math.random() * (((balance/25) * 60) - 0) + 1));
     double cost = (call.getDuration()/60 * 25);
     balance = getBalance() - cost;
     updateCallHistory(call);
    }
```

and I then need to be able to search the arraylist callHistory it is updating and find the destination that has been called the most number of times and return that number and count.

Then I will call these values for each "phone" a person has and print the destination with the highest count across all "phones" as well as it's count.

I've been looking around and have found information on finding occurrences of a particular object, but not been able to figure out how to check a particular field within that object instead of the object itself.

Sorry if this sounds convoluted but I'm getting quite confused and have run out of ideas, my hash mapping isn't very strong yet and I couldn't tweak the examples I've found to do what I want.

based on comments below I have

```
public void mostCalled(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<Phonecall,Integer> map = new HashMap<Phonecall, Integer>();  
        for(int i=0;i<callHistory.size();i++){              
            Integer count = map.get(callHistory.get(i));         
            map.put(callHistory.get(i), count==null?1:count+1);  
        }  
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

but I do not know how to use the destination field of Phonecall instead of the object itself.

Would something like this be more suitable:

```
public void mostCalled(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  
        for(Phonecall call : callHistory)
        {
            Integer count = map.get(call.destination);         
            map.put(call.destination, count==null?1:count+1);  
        }  
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Map<Phonecall, Integer>` wich has the calls as key and as value the count. Iterate through your ArrayList and while doing that fill the Map.

Comment: In order to answer your last question we better see the PhoneCall declaration. However, I suggest you not to scan the List using a for with a counter, you better use an iterator. If tomorrow the ArrayList becomes a LinkedList, then you will learn how better it is!

Comment: Added another attempt using string instead of object and an iterator instead of a counter.  Does that look more like what I should be starting with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to declare a `Map<String, Integer> phoneCount` which would hold a phone number as the key and the number of calls made to this number as the value.

Then, you would loop through the `ArrayList` of `PhoneCall` objects and build the map. The record having the biggest value is the one you are looking for.

Comment: How would I store the "destination" field of the PhoneCall object as the key instead of the object itself?

Comment: I declared it as Map<String, Integer> such as you can put the destination phone number which is probably a String.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that wants to do this, this is what I ended up with.

```
public void mostCalled() 
    {
        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  
        for(Phonecall call : callHistory)
        {
            Integer count = map.get(call.destination);         
            map.put(call.destination, count==null?1:count+1);  
        }  
        List<String> maxKeyList=new ArrayList<String>();
        Integer maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) 
        {
             if(entry.getValue() > maxValue) 
             {
                 maxValue = entry.getValue();
                 maxKeyList.add(entry.getKey());
             }
        }
        System.out.println("Phone numbers called the most : "+maxKeyList);
    }
```